Scikit-fem wire heat simulation problem (Crank-Nicolson)
I'm trying to simulate the temperature evolution in a cable due to the Joule effect. I already have a code that allows me to simulate conduction in a cable but not temporally. I've heard that one possible method is the Crank-Nicolson method. I've tried to look into it but I can't seem to understand how to apply this method to my code. Maybe there's an expert in this kind of simulation who will come across this message. Thanks in advance for the help!
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Optional
import numpy as np

from skfem import *
from skfem.helpers import dot, grad
from skfem.models.poisson import mass, unit_load
from skfem.io.json import from_file

joule_heating = 5.
heat_transfer_coefficient = 7.
thermal_conductivity = {'core': 101.,  'annulus': 11.}

mesh = from_file(Path(__file__).parent / 'meshes' / 'disk.json')
radii = sorted([np.linalg.norm(mesh.p[:, mesh.t[:, s]], axis=0).max() for s in mesh.subdomains.values()])


@BilinearForm
def conduction(u, v, w):
    return dot(w['conductivity'] * grad(u), grad(v))


convection = mass

element = ElementQuad1()
basis = Basis(mesh, element)

basis0 = basis.with_element(ElementQuad0())

conductivity = basis0.zeros()
for s in mesh.subdomains:
    conductivity[basis0.get_dofs(elements=s)] = thermal_conductivity[s]

L = asm(conduction, basis, conductivity=basis0.interpolate(conductivity))

facet_basis = FacetBasis(mesh, element, facets=mesh.boundaries['perimeter'])
H = heat_transfer_coefficient * asm(convection, facet_basis)

core_basis = Basis(mesh, basis.elem, elements=mesh.subdomains['core'])
f = joule_heating * asm(unit_load, core_basis)

temperature = solve(L + H, f)

T0 = {
    "skfem": (basis.probes(np.zeros((2, 1))) @ temperature)[0],
    "exact": (
        joule_heating
        * radii[0] ** 2
        / 4
        / thermal_conductivity["core"]
        * (
            2 * thermal_conductivity["core"] / radii[1] / heat_transfer_coefficient
            + (
                2
                * thermal_conductivity["core"]
                / thermal_conductivity["annulus"]
                * np.log(radii[1] / radii[0])
            )
            + 1
        )
    ),
}


if __name__ == '__main__':

    from os.path import splitext
    from sys import argv
    from skfem.visuals.matplotlib import draw, plot, savefig

    ax = draw(mesh)
    plot(basis, temperature, ax=ax, colorbar=True)
    savefig(splitext(argv[0])[0] + '_solution.png')

I hope someone can explain to me how to make this simulation temporal. If anyone has an example, please don't hesitate to share.
